# ArrayList with multiple arguments (User input)

Tags: java, arraylist, arguments

I am trying to create a App base on user input with ArrayList. But there is some problem that I need to understand first.

PS: I want to try with normal value first before going into user input. And this is just a rough sketch up to make me understand how to use multiple arguments in a arraylist.

This is the Student

```
package test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private Date DOB;
    private String[] friend;
    private String school;

    public Student(String name, Date DOB, String[] friend, String school) {
        this.name = name;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.friend = friend;
        this.school = school;

    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println("Released Date : " + df.format(DOB));
        System.out.println("Best Friend : " + friend[0] + ", " + friend[1]);
        System.out.println("Director : " + school);

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

This is the StudentApp

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentApp {
    private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public void start() {
        addStudent();
    }

    public void addStudent() {
        System.out.println("- Add Student Info -");
        students.add(/* Need to ask the user to input their information like their name,DOB,friend,school*/);
    }

}
```

how can I add in values to the arraylist if there is multiple arguments needed? (String, Date, String[], String). Because when I tried adding some value with the correct arguments needed into the students.add, it will show me an error saying

> The method add(int, Student) in the type ArrayList is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, null, String, String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is add wrong elements in a list.

The list you `students` is a list of `Student`. So as pointed out earlier, `students.add()` would only accept objects of type `Student`.

You will have to do something like:

```
System.out.println("- Add Student Info -");
String name = ""; //Get name from user
Date dob = new Date(); //Get DOB from user
String[] friends = new String[]{"Friend1", "Friend2"}; //Get a list of friends from user
String school = ""; //Get school from user

students.add(new Student(name, dob, friends, school));
//OR students.add(0, new Student(name, dob, friends, school)); //Replace 0 with any index
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the object of `Student` class in your `ArrayList`

```
students.add(new Student(String, String, String, String))
```

Comment: I like how you posted your answer 9 secs before mine :-).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple arguments to an `ArrayList`, at least not in that form. It looks like what you really want to do is:

```
students.add(new Student(/*whatever info*/));
```

If you really want multiple elements in an `ArrayList`, do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>(); // or if you know all of them are Strings, String[]
list.add(new Object[]{arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4});
```

Better than that is to create a special class, something like:

```
class Data{
    private String[] data;

    public Data(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4){
        data = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
    }

    public String getElement(int index){
        return data[index];
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Data(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4));
```